# Android trying to use java.awt,Color but its failing to include

Tags: android, image, java

I am trying to use some libraries from the jre but i cant seem to import them as external jars to my android project. 
Is this even possible ?
I am using an image recognition library and this class is importing
java.awt.Color
javax.imageio.imagereader
etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JRE libraries contain native code so they cannot be distributed with your app. There are some attempts to port AWT to Android, but I don't think any are complete drop-in replacements. If you have source for the library you are using, you can try to adapt it to Android equivalents of the AWT components that it relies on.